# Specializing function template in separate .cpp file

Tags: c++, templates

I've written a template for a very simple print function, and I've put it in a library of custom functions that all deal with console IO.

I've written a second library for a specific project, that is a child of the original. It specializes one of the templates.

I'm running in to an error which (I suspect) is being caused by the call in main.cpp occurring before the declaration of the specialized template. The error contains this line:

```
 In instantiation of 'static void baseIO::print(S) [with s = std::vector<int>]'
```

Which means its calling `baseIO::print()` instead of `specialIO::print()`

I tried making `specialIO::print()` a regular function instead of a template, and declaring it as normal in the header, but that denied main.cpp access to the base template.

Is there a way to make my specialization usable in main.cpp WITHOUT having to <strike>declare</strike> implement it there?

```
//in main.cpp
#include <vector>
#include "specialIO.h"

main(){
    std::vector<int> myVector;
    specialIO::print(myVector);
    specialIO::print("hello world");
    return 1;
}
```

.

```
//in baseIO_templates.cpp - templates are outside of the baseIO.cpp file because of linker errors
template<typename S>     //primary template
void baseIO::print(S str){
    std::cout << str;
}

//baseIO.h
class baseIO{
public:
    template<typename S> //primary template
    static void print(S str);
}
#include "baseIO_templates.cpp"
```

.

```
//specialIO.cpp
template<>               //specialized template
void static specialIO::print(vector<int> myVector){
    for(int i : myVector){
        baseIO::print(i)
    }
}

//specialIO.h
class uberIO : public baseIO {
    //empty
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason, why you always copy the vector and not pass it by a const ref?

Answer (score 0):

All template code must be available to the compiler when the code is called. So if you have declared `template<T> void SomeFunction(T x);` - then the compiler will need to know the definition of `SomeFunction` when you call it with `std::string`, or `float` or `MyStruct`. Since there is no way the compiler can figure out how to find the right implementation (or generate code for the right implementation) if it didn't know the type until now...

Therefore, you can't put template instantiations in a .cpp file - it is possible to put the specialization in a .cpp file if you declare them in a header-file, so:

```
class specialIO : public baseIO {
 public:
   template<>void static print<std::vector>(std::vector<int> v);
};
```

But if you leave it empty, the compiler won't even know there is such a print function, so can't call it - it will try to pass the `std::vector` into the regular `baseIO::print<T>`, which won't work because it's not capable of doing that.

Comment: I suspected I needed to include something in the header, but had no idea what. love the thoroughness of your explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Added this to my code, but now I get "error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class specialIO'